# Check data returned from server is not empty

Tags: swift

I receive a string from a server: even if the `responseCode` can be 200, the 'server guys' told me the server API can return, under some circumstances, 200 and a body with no data at all.

I tried the following, but I'm not sure it is enough (or done well):

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

// verify we have data
guard (data != nil) else {print("error, empty data"); return}

// conversion to String
let d = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) as! String

// verify data is not empty
guard d.characters.count > 0 else {print("error, string is empty string"); return}
```

Any tip is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you should also check this condition, in case we get error from server with data

```
 if error != nil {
         return 
        }
```

Comment: As I just said, I have not included here the code related to the error since it was not useful